Reducing Subgraph Isomorphism problem to an instance of the Hamiltonian Cycle problem
How to reduce a Subgraph Isomorphism problem to an instance of the Hamiltonian Cycle problem (not the other way around)?

If you claim that you have a polynomial time algorithm for Hamiltonian Cycle and need a polynomial time algorithm for Subgraph Isomorphism, that should be your question.

Let $G$ be a graph and $H=C_n$.

This is not the (implied) reduction asked in the question.  I am looking for SI --to --> HC reduction. Not otherway around.  Even a reduction to SAT from SI would be helpful (using Cook-Levin Theorem)

Well, SI is a generalization of HC, so it is a proof of the NP-hardness of SI.

Yes, but that was not my question. Your "answer" is well known!I have a P-time solution to HC. If I can find an existing reduction of SI--> HC, then I could solve SI too. The only other way is to go through the long path of SI--> SAT --> HC. And even SI--> SAT is not known.

I see... you have a polynomial time algorithm for Hamiltonian Cycle and need one for Subgraph Isomorphism?
